# Possible slab memory leak related to bio and btrfs?

Tags: kernel, memory, btrfs, out-of-memory, memory-leaks

I'm currently running a rebuild on a btrfs NAS (~20TB) that had a drive failure. It's going to take a few days. My problem is about once every 24 hours the RAM filled up and the kernel starts killing off processes until the whole system dies.

`htop` shows this as user process memory usage but no user processes show any significant memory usage:

[image]

`free` shows this as buffered/cached ram:

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        923M        1.0G         16M         13G        5.0G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
```

[I finally tracked it down with `slabtop`](http://pastebin.com/FWbn3S3C)

As you can see `bio` has an insane amount of slab usage. Running `sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` clears up the `dentry` usage but does not affect `bio` at all.

This NAS is running Rockstor which is based on CentOS. The machine in question is on kernel `4.4.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64`. There is nothing of note in kernel messages until the RAM usage gets to the point where processes start getting killed off.

Is this a memory leak bug in BTRFS or the kernel? If this is a bug that needs to be reported, how to I determined which package to report it to?

Is there a way to clear the cache usage by `bio` so I can complete this RAID rebuild without rebooting the system once a day when it crashes from running out of RAM?

And just out of morbid curiosity, if this is kernel caching why does `htop` report it as user process memory usage (green bar)?